QGIS - How to take the original DSM and replace 0 values ONLY with the interpolated values
I have an original DSM which has 0 values in it
I've created a mask (sectioning the affected area), and interpolated it.
I now want to replace the original DSMs values of 0 with the interpolated values. If the original DSM value is more than 0 then it should remain as is.
How can I do this?
Tried the following in QGIS raster calculator
("DSM@1" != 0) * "DSM@1" + ("DSM@1" = 0) * "Interpolated@1"

However, it only outputs a new raster to the extent of the interpolated raster, which is a subsection. I want the extent to be that of the original DSM

Here maybe?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387206/replace-raster-values-by-another-raster-in-qgis
